# Type issue for a resolved promise (Svelte/TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, axios, svelte, typing

I have the following simplified Svelte code in Typescript:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { env } from "$env/dynamic/public";
    import type { Submission } from '../models/submission';

    let submissionUuid: string | undefined;
    let submissionStatusResponse = Promise.resolve(String);
    // let submissionStatusResponse = Promise<string>; // not sure about the difference

    const postSubmission = async (file: File): Promise<Partial<Submission>> => {
        const formData = { file: file };
        const { data, status } = await axios.post(env.PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/submissions/', formData, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        });
        if (status === 200) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
        }
    };

    const getSubmissionStatus = async (uuid: string) => {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get(env.PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/submissions/' + uuid);
        if (status === 200) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return data.status;
        }
    };

    function handleSubmit() {
        let submissionResponse: Promise<Partial<Submission>> = postSubmission(
            document.getElementById('file').files[0]
        );
        submissionResponse.then((submission) => {
            submissionUuid = submission.uuid;
            submissionStatusResponse = getSubmissionStatus(submissionUuid);
        });
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <label for="file">Select a file</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    {#await submissionStatusResponse then submissionStatus}
        {submissionStatus}
    {:catch error}
        Error getting submission status from API: {error.message}
    {/await}
</form>
```

But in the web page the it renders the string `function String() { [native code] }` instead of the resolved value of `submissionStatus`.

There must be indeed a type issue since the following Typescript alert is raised on the component `Status`, when passing the *supposedly* resolved `submissionStatus` string: `Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you share more info from the error? What line does it occur on? Why do you assign `= Promise.resolve(String);`? Do you mean for this to be a type annotation?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: there is no error when running the component, but it renders the string "function String() { [native code] }" instead of the resolved value of submissionStatus. This is the case however the submissionStatusResponse would be originally typed. Also, Typescript raises an alert "Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'string'", if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning `submissionStatusResponse` rather than annotating it:

```
let submissionStatusResponse = Promise.resolve(String);
```

So then `Promise` can resolve `String` right away. The result is `function String() { [native code] }` (try doing `console.log(String)` for comparison).

I think you want:

```
let submissionStatusResponse: Promise<string>; // A promise that will return a string
```

Then, once the promise is resolved, a string will be returned.